# MySQL Workbench With Wamp Server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following problem , I downloaded Wamp server, then I downloaded MySQL Workbench then I connected it to a database defined in MySQL Wamp server, now I want to make updates to this Database tables automatically without  apply the changes every time ? Is it possible ? 
[image: MySQL Workbench]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible if you want this changes to be permanent. If you want this changes to be permanent then you have to click the apply button.

Comment: Is there a way to do this inside the Workbench ? what if I import a data base ? And then make changes to it  ?

Comment: Usually, how you do is, after you selected from a table like above, let say you want to change a data in the displayed record, you double click the cell of interest and make changes then you click apply. If not you have to issu and sql update command manually.

Comment: Ok I thinks this is annoying, I want to double click the cell  and make changes then these changes automatically saved just like php myadmin can you suggest a solution to that ?

Comment: Hi, don't worry about it. No, this cannot be done in MySQL Workbench. The solution that you want is not in my control and I say this because it would be part of the tool itself and there is none at this moment that I know of.

Comment: I was pondering on your first comment about importing database. What you could do is first export the data using MySQL Workbench as insert statements for the selected table. Modify the exported data then import to the desired table.